# How to avoid de-reference overhead of pointers, using references in containers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm encountering a design challenge. There is a huge `std::vector<int>` called `O` say of size 10000. There are two many objects of type `Foo`, `f_1`...`f_n`. Each `Foo` has an internal `std::vector<int>` which is a suborder of `O`. For example:

```
O = 1, 2, ..., 100000
f_1.order = 1, 2, 3
f_2.order = 1, 4, 16
f_3.order = 100, 101, 102
// ...
```

The main requirement is to update corresponding values of `O` when a `f_n` changes its values. Length and contents of all `Foo` objects are knows at construction time and not supposed to change during their lifetime. For example it's known that `f_1` holds first, second and third elements of `O`.

The obvious solution is to use pointers of course. `Foo` may hold a `std::vector<int*>` which each element points to underlying data of original order (`O`).

On the other hand, my program do some heavy calculations using `Foo` objects. So I'm looking for a method to remove overhead of pointer dereferencing. It would be nice if design allow me to use some sort of `std::vector<int&>` but it's not possible (I guess because `vector<T>` needs presence of `T*`).

A colleague suggested to use `boost::ptr_vector`. Another suggested holding indexes in a `vector<size_t>`...

Comment: Overhead of pointer dereferencing?  Really?

Comment: (1) You cannot user references in containers. (2) References have dereference overhead identical to that of pointers.

Comment: Ouh...prepare for some nice comments. ;)

Comment: A solution to overhead is to use more overhead? Dereferencing a pointer vs indexing a vector and use the result to index other vector? LOL

Comment: Wanna lose virginity without having sex.

Comment: And, note that the overhead with pointers is not the derefence (Its done with one or two assambler instructions), is the posibility of cache misses. If the pointer points to a near memory address, there are no miss, so there is no overhead. On the other hand, your index holding vector solution is not cache friendly.

Comment: @ChristianRau And of course for many downvotes

Comment: I'm assuming a pointer needs to access memory two times and memory is slow. This lead me to the idea : "pointers are a little bit slower than  references" Which seems to be wrong according to downvotes and comments...

Comment: References are the compiler hiding pointers behind your back, nothing more.

Comment: @Kevin In the first year of university, I'm told that a reference type is another name for a variable. They didn't tell much more about implementation details and I didn't searched for. After passing compiler course, I got the wrong perception that a reference type is an item in symbol table with a repeated field for it's original value... Now I know that I need a complete review of basic programming and compiler courses.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure any overhead that might be introduced by using pointers would be dwarfed by the overhead of method lookups, especially if they're virtual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sound as premature optimization. Dereference a pointer is ridiculously cheap.

> The obvious solution is to use pointers of course. Foo may hold a std::vector which each element points to underlying data of original order (O).

Here a solution, deducting what you need, not using pointers, using std::reference_wrapper and std::ref:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::vector<int>& _data) : dataFull(_data)
    { ; }

    void add(int index)
    {
        assert(index < dataFull.size());

        if(index < references.size())
        {
            // replace
            references[index] = std::ref(dataFull[index]);
        }
        else
        {
            // add n times, need sync with index
            while(index >= references.size())
            {
                references.push_back(std::ref(dataFull[index]));
            }
        }

        // mark as valid index
        indexes.push_back(index);
        // sort for can find with binary_search
        std::sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end());
    }

    int* get(int index)
    {
        if(std::binary_search(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), index))
        {
            return &references[index].get();
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

protected:
    std::vector<int>& dataFull;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int> > references;
    std::vector<int> indexes;
};

int main()
{
    const int size = 1000000;
    std::vector<int> O;
    O.resize(1000000, 0);

    Foo f_1(O);
    f_1.add(1);
    f_1.add(2);
    f_1.add(3);

    Foo f_2(O);
    f_2.add(1);
    f_2.add(4);
    f_2.add(16);

    Foo f_3(O);
    f_3.add(100);
    f_3.add(101);
    f_3.add(102);

    // index 1 is changed, it must affect to all "Foo" that use this index (f_1 and f_2)
    O[1] = 666;

    // checking if it changed
    assert( *f_1.get(1) == 666 );
    assert( *f_2.get(1) == 666 );
    assert(  f_3.get(1) == NULL );

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Performance is same that if you use pointer, but std::reference_wrapper can be integrated best in templated code because you have T& and don't need have code for T* and T&.

Have indexes in other vector, only is useful if your struct is ordered by multiple criteria.

I show a example with a vector, where T is a struct complex with two fields. I can reorder this vector with 2 criterias, without touch the original.

```
template <typename T>
struct Index
{
    typedef typename bool(*Comparator)(const T&, const T&);

    Index(std::vector<T>& _data, Comparator _comp)
        : dataFull(_data)
        , comp(_comp)
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < dataFull.size(); ++i)
        {
            add(i);
        }
        commit();
    }

    void commit()
    {
        std::sort(references.begin(), references.end(), comp);
    }

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T> >& getReference() {return references;}

protected:

    void add(int index)
    {
        assert(index < dataFull.size());
        references.push_back(std::ref(dataFull[index]));
    }

protected:
    std::vector<T>& dataFull;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T> > references;
    Comparator comp;
};

int main()
{
    struct ComplexData
    {
        int field1;
        int field2;
    };

    // Generate vector
    const int size = 10;
    std::vector<ComplexData> data;
    data.resize(size);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        ComplexData& c = data[i];
        c.field1 = i;
        c.field2 = size - i;
    }

    // Vector reordered without touch original
    std::cout << "Vector data, ordered by field1" << std::endl;
    {
        Index<ComplexData> f_1(data, 
            [](const ComplexData& a, const ComplexData& b){return a.field1 < b.field1;});
        auto it = f_1.getReference().begin();
        auto ite = f_1.getReference().end();
        for(; it != ite; ++it)
        {
            std::cout << "-> " << it->get().field1 << " - " << it->get().field2 << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // Vector reordered without touch original
    std::cout << "Vector data, ordered by field2" << std::endl;
    {
        Index<ComplexData> f_2(data, 
            [](const ComplexData& a, const ComplexData& b){return a.field2 < b.field2;});
        auto it = f_2.getReference().begin();
        auto ite = f_2.getReference().end();
        for(; it != ite; ++it)
        {
            std::cout << "-> " << it->get().field1 << " - " << it->get().field2 << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would this be faster than pointers, given that references have the same overhead as pointers?

Answer (score 6):

I would say that optimizing for pointer dereferencing overhead is pointless. Let's look at some example code:

```
void bar(int i);

void foo(int* p, int i)
{
    bar(*p);
    bar(i);
}
```

And now let's look at the assembly of it:

```
void foo(int* p, int i)
{
                      push   rbx
                      mov    ebx, esi

    bar(*p);
                      mov    edi, DWORD PTR [rdi]
                      call   a <foo+0xa>

    bar(i);
                      mov    edi, ebx
                      call   11 <foo+0x11>
}
```

There's an "overhead" of one memory read.

As for using references, it's not gonna do anything useful. References may have different semantics to pointers, but underneath, they're still pointers:

```
void foo(int& r)
{
    bar(r);
                      mov    edi,DWORD PTR [rbx]
                      call   20 <_Z3fooPiiRi+0x20>
}
```

There's the same memory read happening.

I'm not sure if this counts as an "answer", but seriously: don't bother.

Answer (score 5):

This cannot be stressed enough - do not optimize your code before you know you have a problem. Pointer dereferencing is not costly, and is usually not the main bottleneck in a program.

Note that references are implemented using pointer dereferencing, so even if you could do `std::vector<int&>`, it would not help.

If you really, really feel you must do something - even though I'm really, totally sure it can't possibly help your performance in any meaningful sense - you could try overlaying the memory. That is, you could define it like this (note that I'm not in any way endorsing this - I'm only pointing it out so that you don't do something worse):

```
std::vector<int> O;

struct Foo {
   int *myData;
   int &operator[](int offset) { return myData[offset]; }
};

O.resize(1000000, 0);
Foo f_1, f_2, ...;
f_1.myData = &(O[0]);
f_2.myData = &(O[3]);

O[0] = 5;
cout << f_1[0]; // prints 5
```

Also, BTW - please, please, please, do not use the name `O` as a variable. Please. It looks like a zero.